# Delayed jobs on crawler Ruby on Rails , Jobs cannot be created for records before they've been persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, delayed-job

I am working on ROR app with mongodb. Basically one of my model class is this :

```
require 'open-uri'   
class StockPrice
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :stock_name, type: String
 field :price, type: Float

 index :stock_name => +1, :updated_at => -1

 def self.price(stock_name)
   #print stock_name
   g=StockPrice.new
   g.crawl(stock_name)
   where(stock_name: stock_name).desc(:updated_at).first.price
end

#Search for the stock in screener.in and get its last price.
def crawl(stock_name)
  company_name=stock_name
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get('http://www.screener.in/')
  form = agent.page.forms[0]
  agent.page.forms[0]["q"]=company_name
  button = agent.page.forms[0].button_with(:value => "Search Company")
  pages=agent.submit(form, button)  
  new_page=pages.uri.to_s
  doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open(new_page))
  row_data = doc.css('.table.draggable.table-striped.table-hover tr.strong td').map     do       |tdata|
      tdata.text
  end
  g=row_data[2]
 StockPrice.create(stock_name:stock_name,price:g)
end
handle_asynchronously :crawl
end
```

Now In my app I want to run crawl function using delayed jobs so that it can run in background For this i am using delayed_jobs_mongoid gem. But i am getting this error when I use handle_asynchronously: Jobs cannot be created for records before they've been persisted

Answer (score 0):

You stated the reasons yourself you the record must persist in database in order to for delayed_job to work

### Solution

instead do something like this

```
def self.price(stock_name)
   #print stock_name
   crawl stock_name
   where(stock_name: stock_name).desc(:updated_at).first.price
end

def self.crawl(stock_name)
  s = StockPrice.new(name: stock_name)
  company_name=stock_name
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get('http://www.screener.in/')
  form = agent.page.forms[0]
  agent.page.forms[0]["q"]=company_name
  button = agent.page.forms[0].button_with(:value => "Search Company")
  pages=agent.submit(form, button)  
  new_page=pages.uri.to_s
  doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open(new_page))
  row_data = doc.css('.table.draggable.table-striped.table-hover tr.strong td').map     do       |tdata|
      tdata.text
  end
  g=row_data[2]
  s.price = g 
  s.save
end
```

this make sense more because `crawl` is technically(in real world) should be `class` method instead of instance method

Comment: first I am using my previous code with function now a class method as your code was generating other error. S econd handle_asynchronously :crawl , is giving an error that is there is no function crawl and when i do StockPrice.crawl it gives undefined method `crawl' for :StockPrice:Symbol

Comment: Scope you have to be aware of scope

Comment: What I meant is that **handle_ayshronously** scope is not called in class scope